# helm-mini - narrow down to buffers selection with specified major mode

Tags: helm, helm-sources, helm-selection

currently, to narrow down the buffers withshell mode, I'd invoke helm-mini, and then type "shell". I wonder
   how can I narrow down the selections using lisp? So I could have a
   function with a list pre-defined groups for quickly jumps between buffers.

It would be handy if I work in a R/Python projects.

Comment: To narrow down `sh-mode` buffers, you should use `*sh` instead. You can read the related documentation with `C-h m`.

Comment: thanks, that's quicker! does * is a special character in this context?

Comment: Yes, it is. Here is the online doc about this: https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki/Buffers#buffers-by-major-mode